# Failed to setting up TensorFlow With OpenCL using SYCL

Tags: tensorflow, opencl, ubuntu-16.04

I set up TensorFlow with SYCL on Ubuntu 16.04 / AMD RX480 by following https://www.codeplay.com/portal/03-30-17-setting-up-tensorflow-with-opencl-using-sycl, and skipped installing the AMD OpenCL headers due to fglrx version conflict.

Then, failed when：

1. Either running： $ bazel test --config=sycl -k --test_timeout 1600
   -- //tensorflow/... -//tensorflow/contrib/... -//tensorflow/java/... -//tensorflow/compiler/...

returned：
    /home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/testlogs/tensorflow/go/test/test.log

```
Executed 1 out of 634 tests: 84 tests pass, 549 fail to build and 1 fails locally.
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
```

where test.log shows:

```
[[ ! -x go ]]
[[ -x /usr/local/go/bin/go ]]
export
PATH=.:/home/opt/anaconda2/envs/sycl/bin:/home/opt/anaconda2/bin:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/bin:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/bin:/home/ai/bin:/home/ai/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/go/bin

PATH=.:/home/opt/anaconda2/envs/sycl/bin:/home/opt/anaconda2/bin:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/bin:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/bin:/home/ai/bin:/home/ai/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
export
GOPATH=/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/_tmp/3e13e1018d21b8204dd1d98027854067/go

GOPATH=/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/_tmp/3e13e1018d21b8204dd1d98027854067/go
mkdir -p
/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/_tmp/3e13e1018d21b8204dd1d98027854067/go/src/github.com/tensorflow
ln -s
/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow
/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/_tmp/3e13e1018d21b8204dd1d98027854067/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
export
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow

LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow
++ uname -s
OS=Linux
[[ Linux = \L\i\n\u\x ]]
[[ -z
/usr/local/computecpp/lib:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/lib:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/lib:  
]]
export
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow:/usr/local/computecpp/lib:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/lib:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/lib:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow:/usr/local/computecpp/lib:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/lib:/home/opt/OpenSource/torch/install/lib:
++ go version
echo 'Go version: go version go1.7.4 linux/amd64'
Go version: go version go1.7.4 linux/amd64
go test github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/op
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so: undefined reference to cl::sycl::program::create_program_for_kernel_impl(std::string, unsigned char const*, int, char const* const*, std::shared_ptr<cl::sycl::detail::context>)
/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so: undefined reference to cl::sycl::program::get_kernel_impl(std::string)
const
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status # github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so: undefined reference to cl::sycl::program::create_program_for_kernel_impl(std::string, unsigned char const*, int, char const* const*, std::shared_ptr<cl::sycl::detail::context>)
/home/ai/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ai/03759b09788dc48db1c2f1f857f3711b/execroot/tensorflow-opencl/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/go/test.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so: undefined reference to cl::sycl::program::get_kernel_impl(std::string)
const
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
FAIL    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go [build failed]
FAIL    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/op [build failed]
```

2. Or running: $ bazel build --local_resources 2048,.5,1.0 -c opt --config=sycl //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

returned：

```
/home/opt/OpenSource/TensorFlow/tensorflow-opencl/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/BUILD:108:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/compiler/xla/service:versioned_computation_handle' failed: computecpp failed: error executing command external/local_config_sycl/crosstool/computecpp -Wall -msse3 -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG '-std=c++11' -MD -MF ... (remaining 103 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
In file included from
tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.cc:16:0:
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h:33:19: error:  
expected type-specifier before 'int64'
    using Version = int64;

./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h:36:3:  
error: Version does not name a type
    Version version;

./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h:38:3:  
error: string does not name a type
    string ToString() const;

./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h: In member function bool xla::VersionedComputationHandle::operator==(const
xla::VersionedComputationHandle&) const:
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h:41:13: error:  
version was not declared in this scope
             (version == other.version);

./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h:41:30: error:  
const struct xla::VersionedComputationHandle has no member named version
             (version == other.version);

./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h: In member function bool xla::VersionedComputationHandle::operator<(const
xla::VersionedComputationHandle&) cons':
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h:46:15: error:  
version was not declared in this scope
               (version < other.version)));

./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.h:46:31: error:  
'const struct xla::VersionedComputationHandle' has no member named version
               (version < other.version)));

tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.cc: At global scope:
tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.cc:22:1:  
error: string does not name a type
  string VersionedComputationHandle::ToString() const {

tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.cc: In function std::ostream& xla::operator<<(std::ostream&, const
xla::VersionedComputationHandle&):
tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/versioned_computation_handle.cc:28:27:  
error: const struct xla::VersionedComputationHandle has no member named ToString out << versioned_handle.ToString();
```

Moreover, both my CPU and GPU seem "untested" to ComputeCPP according to computecpp_info.

Comment: At the moment you'll need to use Ubuntu 14.04 with AMD hardware and this. What branch are you working from? Does the build work without the sycl option? Also what version of ComputeCpp are you using? What does the computecpp_info tool show?

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the first error try `-//tensorflow/go/...` - we did not try the go wrapper yet.

XLA error is confusing as in the crosstool script we are explicitly avoiding compiling "compiler" folder with ComputeCpp (https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/blob/dev/eigen_mehdi/third_party/sycl/crosstool/computecpp.tpl#L46).

Make sure you are on this branch: https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/tree/dev/eigen_mehdi